# Show all rows where a condition is met

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements, subset

i have browsed through stack overflow a bit and have not find an answer to this question, however i found answers to a similar condition and tried to apply it to my situation without success.

So i would like to view all the variables where a condition a = b is met, where a and b are numerical.

Data:

```
people = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7)
b = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 9)

subset(data, a = b)
```

However, this does not lead to my intended output which would be showing all persons where a = b is met.

```
Output 
people a=b
1       
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality operator in R is `==`

Try

```
data <- data.frame(people = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7),
b = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 9))

subset(data, a == b)

    people a b
[1]      1 1 1
[2]      2 3 3
```

Comment: oh, that sounds like a good hack. But how would i able to actually view it

Answer (score 0):

i hope this also is useable

```
people <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a <- c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7)
b <- c(1, 3, 5, 8, 9)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(people,a,b))

#compare "df$a == df$b" returns a vector "TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE"
#this placed in "df[]" returns all rows with true statements

df[df$a == df$b,]
```

Output:

```
  people a b
       1 1 1
       2 3 3
```

extra: (if you just want the people vector)

```
df[df$a == df$b,1]

> 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make dplyr your friend

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(people = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
a = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7),
b = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 9))

# filter by the desired condition, all "a" that are equal to "b"
data %>% 
 filter(a == b) # please note the "==", its not a single "="

  people a b
1      1 1 1
2      2 3 3
```